# Google Sheets Import Function from Fortune 500

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to import the table of Fortune 500 companies for 2019 into Sheets. I've tried the formula

```
=IMPORTXML("https://fortune.com/fortune500/2019/search/","//div[@class='ReactTable']")
```

and some variations of this function but can't get it correct. Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

the website you trying to scrape is under JavaScript control. Google Sheets is not capable of importing JS elements. you can test this simply by disabling JavaScript for a given site and what you are left with is able to be scraped. in your case: nothing:

[image: 0]